# JavaScript GET запрос

Tags: javascript, get, requests

Нужно отправить запрос и получить данные в JSON, делаю так, но получаю ошибки.

```js
async function getData(url = 'https://*****.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/api/issues', data = {}) {
    // Default options are marked with *
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'fields': 'id,login,name,email',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ***************',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',

        },
        redirect: 'follow',
        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    return await response.json();
    console.log(response.json)
}
getData('https://********.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/api/issues', data = {})
```

[image: Ошибки]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У запросов типа `GET` не может быть тела чисто физически. Если вам необходимо передавать `body` используйте метод `POST` например